# What is the result of a stat() call on a file being written to?

Tags: c, unix, ftp, operating-system, solaris

Having a little problem with the `stat()` system call on Solaris 10. I'm doing FTP and at the same time, calling `stat` (to check on file size) on files that are being written to **concurrently** through FTP.

Let's assume that files are being written to a directory while a `stat()` command/call is being called (in parallel). Then would the result of `st_size` in the `struct` be 0?

Or would the `stat` call reflect the current size of the file while FTP is happening?

Is FTP as transactional as I think it is?

Comment: Whether or not it's transactional really depends on the implementation, and not so much on the FTP protocol itself.  I can't remember if FTP communicates the size of the file ahead of the transfer (I think it does), but in that case it may also pre-allocate the space and look like it's the correct size but not actually have all the data yet.  How this happens is definitely an implementation detail and probably not good to rely on--at the very least not without calling out somewhere that you depend on a specific behavior from your FTP service.

Comment: I hope you're not planning on relying on the file size no longer changing to detect that the entire file has been completed transferred.  That completely ignores any error conditions such as dropped connections.

Comment: the problem with using `stat()` is that it only shows what is actually on the disk.   If the disk drive buffers, or if the OS buffers then the values returned from `stat()` will not be the actual size of the file, but rather only how much of the file has actually been written to the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stat()`-call would show you the same as `ls`, since `ls` uses `stat()` (or a similar function from this family) to show the file size and attributes.

So, for all common filesystems, `stat()` would return the current filesize, which will usually constantly grow during the ftp put transaction.

However, an FTP-Server (or even an FTP-client) might choose to create an empty file of the requested target name, write the actual data to a temporary file and rename this file to the real file name after the transfer completed. In this case, `stat()` would return size 0. But this is not the usual way it happens.

Comment: Wonderful answer! Do you happen to know if FTP on Solaris 10 happens to work this way with the temp files and rename?

Comment: The Solaris 10 FTP-Server is based on WU-FTPd, which should directly write to the target files (no tempfile/rename)